# Allow PHP user to Write to Another User's Home Folder

Tags: php, linux

I have a php script that runs as the user 'codex' and I'm trying to get it to create a new directory to be used as a git repo inside of /home/git/repositories/

I added the codex user to the git group but I must have missed some permissions or something because when I sudo into codex and go to the /home/git/ directory and run mkdir I get a permissions denied error. And of course I get the same error running mkdir in php as well.

I'm running on CentOS 5.9

Any help would be appreciated.

--Vince

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure the group has write access (and read and list access while we're at it):

```
chmod g+rwx /home/git
```

You might also want to make sure the directory's group is the `git` group:

```
chgrp git /home/git
```

Comment: Cool, I did it recursively.  Perfect.  Thanks a bunch.